# Can't inject constant to another module config

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The problem is I can't insert constant from one module to another's module config.

Main app:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('identicaApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'identicaApp.common',
    'identicaApp.mainPage',
    'identicaApp.aboutPage',
    'identicaApp.registerPlayer'
]).config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/main'});
}]);
```

common.js:

```
angular.module('identicaApp.common', [])
  .constant('ROOT_PATH', '/static/angular/identica/');
```

and the problem module:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('identicaApp.mainPage', [
    'ngRoute',
    'identicaApp.common'
])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/main', {
    templateUrl: common.ROOT_PATH + 'main_page/main_page.html',
    controller: 'MainPageCtrl'
  });
}])

.controller('MainPageCtrl', [function() {

}]);
```

`common.ROOT_PATH` is not visible by loader...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed to inject the actual constant to your `config` call (e.g. the same way you inject services to controllers), and then you have to reference it by it's name:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('identicaApp.mainPage', [
    'ngRoute',
    'identicaApp.common'
])

// Here you must inject your 'ROOT_PATH' constant
.config(['$routeProvider', 'ROOT_PATH', function($routeProvider, ROOT_PATH) {
  $routeProvider.when('/main', {
    templateUrl: ROOT_PATH + 'main_page/main_page.html', // You must reference it by its name (ROOT_PATH)
    controller: 'MainPageCtrl'
  });
}])

.controller('MainPageCtrl', [function() {

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the constant and use it like this:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider, ROOT_PATH) {
  $routeProvider.when('/main', {
    templateUrl: ROOT_PATH + 'main_page/main_page.html',
    controller: 'MainPageCtrl'
  });
}])
```

If you want to have multiple constant "variables" under `ROOT_PATH` do it like this.

```
angular.module('identicaApp.common')
  .constant('ROOT_PATH', {
    'URL': '/static/angular/identica/',
    'NAME': 'Test',
    'ANOTHER_THING': 'Something'
});
```

Then you can use it this way:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider, ROOT_PATH) {
  $routeProvider.when('/main', {
    templateUrl: ROOT_PATH.URL + 'main_page/main_page.html',
    controller: 'MainPageCtrl'
  });
}])
```